# Erro de sintaxe SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Venho outra vez com um erro parecido na sintaxe do meu SQL. Já tentei algumas vezes e até agora nada.
Se puderem me dar uma ajuda agradeço.
Segue o meu código:

```php
$sql="INSERT INTO processos   
    (
        processo, 
        numero_beneficio, 
        autor, 
        cpf, 
        nit, 
        data_nascimento, 
        nome_mae, 
        nome_aps, 
        codigo_aps, 
        uf_aps, 
        nome_gex, 
        codigo_gex, 
        data_intimacao, 
        data_distribuicao, 
        data_audiencia, 
        processo_prazo,
        processo_destino,
        assunto,
        cod_assunto,
        localizacao
    )
    VALUES";

foreach($dados as $linha_bd)
{                               

$sql=$sql."(
'".$linha_bd['processo']."',
'0006660000',
'".$linha_bd['autor']."',
'".$linha_bd['cpf']."',
'".$linha_bd['nit']."',
'".$linha_bd['data_nascimento']."',
'".$linha_bd['nome_mae']."',
'".$linha_bd['nome_aps']."',
'".$linha_bd['codigo_aps']."',
'".$linha_bd['uf_aps']."',
'".$linha_bd['nome_gex']."',
'".$linha_bd['codigo_gex']."',
'".$linha_bd['data_intimacao']."',
'".$linha_bd['data_distribuicao']."',
'".$linha_bd['data_audiencia']."',
'".$linha_bd['processo_prazo']."',
'".$linha_bd['processo_destino']."',
'".$linha_bd['assunto']."',
'".$linha_bd['cod_assunto']."',
'".$linha_bd['localizacao']."')";
}
$sql=substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1); 

require_once("../frameworks/AS_lib/as_Lib_banco_de_dados.php");
$banco_de_dados=new banco_de_dados();
$banco_de_dados->executa_sql($sql);
```

**Conteúdo da variável $sql:**

> INSERT INTO processos         (           processo,           numero_beneficio, 
>             autor,              cpf,            nit,            data_nascimento,            nome_mae, 
>             nome_aps,           codigo_aps,             uf_aps,             nome_gex,           codigo_gex,
>             data_intimacao,             data_distribuicao,              data_audiencia, 
>             processo_prazo,             processo_destino,           assunto,            cod_assunto,
>             localizacao         )       VALUES(
>       '00000022620154036304',
>       '0006660000',
>       'ROMILDO CARLOS RIBEIRO MENDES',
>       '12585255859',
>       '',
>       '1969-02-22',
>       'ROSILDA MATOS MENDES',
>       '',
>       '',
>       '',
>       '',
>       '',
>       '2015-03-10',
>       '2015-01-15 13:07:30',
>       '2015-09-21 14:45:00',
>       '2015-04-09',
>       '',
>       '040104 - APOSENTADORIA ESPECIAL (ART. 57/8) - BENEF. EM ESPÉCIE/ CONCESSÃO/         CONVERSÃO/ RESTABELECIMENTO/ COMPLEMENTAÇÃO',

**Erro:**

> »¿SQL invÃ¡lido: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(    '00000439020154036304', '0006660000',
>   'MARCOS DE ALMEIDA',    '08782952833',    ' at line 44

Comment: Você precisa informar qual é o erro ou pq esse resultado não é o esperado. `$sql` está formatada corretamente imprima seu valor para checar isso. Depedendo do caso é possível simplicar isso com usando um select como valores do insert.

Comment: O erro que ocorre é o seguinte(SQL invÃ¡lido: Você tem um erro em sua sintaxe SQL; verifique o manual que corresponde à sua versão do servidor MySQL para o direito de utilizar sintaxe próximo), e com este erro ele não faz o INSERT no banco.

Comment: Se o insert tem vários `values` é necessario separar eles por virgula e depois remover a última com `substr`.

Comment: Dê um `echo` do `$sql` e poste aqui

Comment: pronto..coloquei o echo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se têm `n values` em um `insert`, esses precisam ser separados por vírgula:

```
insert into [table_name] (column_1, column_2, ...)
values (value_1, value_2, ...), (value_3, value_4, ...)
```

No seu código aparentemente você quer fazer isso, você até faz um substring para remover a vírgula após o `foreach`, porém você esqueceu de concatenar a vírgula ao final de cada conjunto de values:

```
'".$linha_bd['localizacao']."')";
```

Altere para:

```
'".$linha_bd['localizacao']."'),";
```

Comment: Obrigado luis Henrique, funcionou agora que coloquei a virgula,